# How do I run an infinitely looping coroutine in a different thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.6, python-asyncio, discord.py

I'm trying to run an infinite loop to check a web server every 20 seconds, and if it finds something, I want it to send a message to a discord channel via my discord bot. However, I'm neither quite sure how asyncio works because I haven't used async/await much nor do I know how to actually implement this.

I've tried a few things:

```py
async def poll():
    ...
    await send()

threading.Thread(target = poll).start()
```

This fails because I don't `await` the `poll` function. If I don't include the `async` in `async def poll` that obviously fails because then the `await send()` isn't valid.

```py
async def poll():
    ...
    await send()

asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(poll(), asyncio.get_event_loop()) # this freezes the rest of my program and prevents my discord bot from working correctly
asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(poll(), asyncio.new_event_loop()) # this warns me saying "coroutine poll was never awaited" and doesn't seem to execute the loop
```

I doubt I'm supposed to use threads with asyncio. But how would I make an infinite loop run in parallel to the rest of my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want this for a discord bot and using discord.py, then you can use `discord.ext.tasks.loop` or a background task.

Loop Example: [Here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/#recipes)

Background Task Example: [Here](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/background_task.py)

None of this will affect your bot, until you are not using a blocking module like `requests` or `time.sleep()`